# Append array item to DOM element with corresponding index (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop, append

Lets say I have three `divs` in my HTML

```
<div>
    <h2>This is div 1</h2>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>This is div 2</h2>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>This is div 3</h2>
</div>
```

Also, I have a JavaScript array made of three nested arrays:

```
var array = [ 
    [ "<p>Bla bla</p>", "<p>Other stuff</p>"], 
    [ "<p>Another paragraph</p>"], 
    [ "<p>Yet another</p>", "<p>yes</p>", "<p>yes</p>" ] 
    ];
```

I am sure that this array will always have three members, just like the number of `divs`.

What I want to do is append the content of each of the nested arrays of the main array to the div with the corresponding number.

Something like:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    $('div').eq( i ).append( array[i] );
}
```

The above code doesn't work but I think my intention is clear.

You can find a working example here => http://jsfiddle.net/G8BsK/

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this...

```
.append( array[i] );
```

to this...

```
.append( array[i].join('') );
```

Although I would highly recommend taking the DOM selection out of the loop, and caching it.

```
var divs = $('div');
for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    divs.eq( i ).append( array[i].join('') );
}
```

...or just do this...

```
$('div').append(function(i) {
    return array[i].join('');
});
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, it works like this. I forgot to join them. :) Btw in my actual code I have the dom elements cached.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
var array = [
    ["<p>Bla bla</p>", "<p>Other stuff</p>"],
    ["<p>Another paragraph</p>"],
    ["<p>Yet another</p>", "<p>yes</p>", "<p>yes</p>"]
    ];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var arr = array[i];
    for (var m = 0; m < arr.length; m++) {
        $('div').eq(i).append(arr[m]);
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G8BsK/2/

Answer (score 0):

it's because the array values being appended are arrays themselves, not the html strings.  You have to join them.

```
    for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        $('div').eq( i ).append( array[i].join('') );
    }
```

will work. the only difference is the 'array[i].join('')